# Mongo add new key-value pair in $group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents like:

```
{
 "tagName": "Tag1",
 "value": 1,
 "ts": "2020/01/01 20:00"
},

{
 "tagName": "Tag2",
 "value": 2,
 "ts": "2020/01/01 20:00"
},

{
 "tagName": "Tag3",
 "value": 3,
 "ts": "2020/02/01 20:00"
}
```

I'd like to group the documents by `ts` and dictionarized the `tagName` and `value`.
so the intention output would be:

```
[

 {
  "Tag1": 1
  "Tag2": 2,
  "ts": "2020/01/01 20:00"
 },
 
 {
  "Tag3": 3,
  "ts": "2020/02/01 20:00"
 }

]
```

I've tried the following pipeline:

```
  {
    $group: {
      '_id': '$ts',
      'output': {
        $push: {
          '$t': '$v'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `$group` by `ts`, you should add `tagName` and `value` to an array -> convert it back to `tagName: value` by `$arrayToObject` then merge it back to root to get your expected result.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zfulGTuHyJC)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$ts",
      "tags": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$tagName",
          "v": "$value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "ts": "$_id",
      "tagsObj": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$tags"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            _id: "$_id",
            
          },
          "$tagsObj"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```